# How to encrypt & decrypt message using x509 certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

To my knowledge a x509 certificate is used to distribute the public key, which in my case is a RSA key, thus I can encrypt a message with it, but without knowing the private key I couldn't get the message back. I created the keys on my linux virtual machine and copied them over to windows to use in my project and I obtain them this way:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("./certificates/cert" + LoginController.getLoggedUser().getID() + ".crt");
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
Certificate c = cf.generateCertificate(inputStream);
myCert = (X509Certificate) c;
```

Now I use the certificate for two things, first to validate if a user can login into the app, and secondly I have to encrypt/decrypt a message I hide inside a picute using steganography. So I'd like to know which file contains my private key and how to load it into my program possibly using the Java SE API? (P.S. I have the CA body and everything still on my virtual machine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The private key should be in the keystore generated by `keytool` (and ideally nowhere else -- private keys are not meant to be distributed, hence the name).

Looks like you can access keystores via an instance of [`java.security.KeyStore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html). You'll need the password you used when generating the keystore; it's one of the parameters to the `load` method.

Comment: Hi, what I want to do is crypt my message using the public key and decrypt the message using the private key, it's just for a school assignment and security isn't a big issue here. Can I generate certificates using `keytool`?

Comment: Yes, you can. Create a key pair, use it to create a CSR (which `keytool` can also generate), then use the CSR and your key pair to create a self-signed certificate. Won't be too useful in the wild, as it's not signed by a trusted CA...but it'll work well enough for learning purposes.

Comment: You could skip the certificate bit, though, considering you have no real need to prove your identity during all this. All you really need are the keys, whichi can be created independently of any certificate.

Comment: Can you give me a link that explains how to do that ?

Comment: OK, it's even easier than i thought. :P  A quick google gives me  https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-java-keytool.html

Comment: `keytool -genkeypair` _automatically_ creates a selfsigned cert, and has since at least j6 during the W-Bush administration. You don't have to do anything else. See the man page for `keytool` or [the Java documentation website under 'tools reference'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/keytool.htm)